# Best practices для создания in memory хранилища используя HashMap

Tags: java, многопоточность, хранение-данных, java-hashmap, best-practice

**Задача**:

Реализовать in memory хранилище с использованием HashMap наилучшим и потокобезопасным способом.

**Вопросы**:

1. Существуют ли best practicies или паттерны для реализации такого хранилища?
2. Можно ли считать такой выбор неоптимальным и почему?

**Комментарий**:

На данный момент я знаю достаточно мощный инструмент для реализации in memory storage, используя H2, однако вопрос больше нацелен на базовые возможности JDK.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите потокобезопасную реализацию `Map`, рекомендую `ConcurentHashMap` из пакета `java.util.concurrent`. 
Методы внутри такой реализации уже синхронизированы, причем намного эффективнее, чем в `Collections.synchronizedMap`.

Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Насчет эффективности здесь сложно говорить без конкретных задач. В любом случае, хранилище в виде базы данных является более эффективным решением, чем создание хранилища средствами одной лишь мапы.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать специальные структуры данных для уменьшения объема хранения и ускорения работы.  Вот например в простейшем случае перед хешмапом еще стоит фильтр Блума который значительно ускоряет работу по проверке наличия блока данных в хранилище.